# Get Canvas X and Y coordinates and show on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I'm currently learning canvas touch event function,I 'm able to draw line on the canvas, now I want to get the x and y coordinates when I draw any lines and show on the screen.please help and teach me how to get the x and y values, thank You!

here is the coding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style>
#contain {
width: 500px;
height: 120px;
top : 15px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;    
}
</style>
<script>
      var canvas;
      var ctx;
      var lastPt=null;
      var letsdraw = false;
      var offX = 10, offY = 20;


    function init() {
        var touchzone = document.getElementById("layer1");
        touchzone.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
        touchzone.addEventListener("touchend", end, false);
        ctx = touchzone.getContext("2d");
      }

      function draw(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (lastPt != null) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastPt.x, lastPt.y);
        ctx.lineTo(e.touches[0].pageX - offX,
                 e.touches[0].pageY - offY);
        ctx.stroke();
  }
  lastPt = {
      x: e.touches[0].pageX - offX,
      y: e.touches[0].pageY - offY
   };
 }

  function end(e) {
   var touchzone = document.getElementById("layer1");
   e.preventDefault();
    // Terminate touch path
    lastPt = null;
   }

    function clear_canvas_width ()
        {
            var s = document.getElementById ("layer1");
            var w = s.width;
            s.width = 10;
            s.width = w;
        }
    </script>    
</head>

<body onload="init()">

<div id="contain">
<canvas id="layer1" width="450" height="440" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;z-index:0; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas> 
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What x and y do you want?

Comment: Eg: the user draw a S shape in the centre of the canvas, how do i find the x and y coordinates of the S shape. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not entirely confident I understand your question.

In the code you posted, you are already obtaining coordinates using e.touches[0].pageX/Y.  The main problem with that is that the pageX/Y values are relative to the page origin.  You are then subtracting fixed offX/Y in your code to try and convert these to canvas-relative coordinates.  Right idea, wrong values.  You need to subtract off the position of the canvas element which can be obtained by summing the offsetX/Y values as you traverse the tree upward using the offsetParent reference.

Something like:

```
offX=0;offY=0;
node = document.getElementById ("layer1");
do {
    offX += node.offsetX;
    offY += node.offsetY;
    node = node.offsetParent;
} while(node);
```

should give you a better value for offX and offY.

If you just want to locate the actual drawing at the end, it would be easiest just to track a bounding box while the user draws.

Comment: Sorry, when I can paste your code inside my program it's not working. can you explain more how can I edit the code, because I'm using chrome at my laptop, I want to fix the canvas drawing at the div, therefore I change the offx and offy value to make the canvas mouse pointer synced. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I want to locate the actual user drawing, may I know how to track a bounding box

Comment: Just track the minimum and maximum x and y values as the user draws.